# l3build clean with multiple checkconfigs

Tags: l3build

I have a `l3build` setup where some checks require more runs than most of the other ones, so I configure `checkconfigs` to make a separate set of checks with a different `testfiledir`.  A simplified example would be:

```lua
-- This is build.lua
bundle = ""
module = "mypackage"
checkruns = 2
checkconfigs = {"build","build-moreruns"}
```

```lua
-- This is build-moreruns.lua
checkruns = 4
testfiledir  = "testfiles-moreruns"
```

The issue is that, sometimes, I'd like to manually clean the generated files for the package, for which there is `l3build clean`. However, `l3build clean` only cleans the directories corresponding to `build.lua`, and leaves the files in `testfiles-moreruns` in place. The only seemingly idiomatic way to do it I found is to run `l3build clean -c build-moreruns`, at which point I'd start considering if just nuking the `build` folder would not easier. But that's not very pretty, thus this question.

I think I get why this is so, so as far as I get, this is intended. But is there a way to instruct `l3build` to clean all generated files in `build` if occasionally I want to do so? (e.g. `l3build clean --all`). Or to configure the `clean` target to include all `checkconfigs`?

Comment: well make a feature request ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was not sure this was a behavior desired generally enough to grant one, and also not sure I was not missing some more obvious way. Do you think a `clean --all` would be a nice feature to have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Besides, I've been pestering you folks enough already of late.  ;-)

Comment: I think l3build clean should directly clean all testdirs related to checkconfigs, this would be more consistent with the l3build check behaviour. If someone wants to clean only one testdir they could use l3build clean -c ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree, but I assumed the current is intended behavior because, if `clean` is used between each element of `checkconfig` (I'm not sure it is, but `unpack` does seem to run every time) the first round of results would be missing when the second finishes. Still, I do have the same feeling that `clean` should be similar to `check` in this regard. I'll open a request then later today. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following suggestion in the comments, I've made a feature request for this at: https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/214.